# Сетевое взаимодействие в Андроид приложениях

Tags: java, android, сеть

Как в Андроид-приложениях программно реализуется сетевое взаимодействие между устройствами?

*Например:* есть приложение Шахматы. Играют два человека на разных устройствах (соединенных (как-то) через интернет/wi-fi)
Один делает ход - движение фигуры отображается у другого и наоборот. Т.е. между устройствами передается какой-то объем данных, который обрабатывается и отображается.

Собственно, вопрос в чем:
**как и через что реализуется подобное взаимодействие? (как его запрограммировать)**

**с чего вообще начать в этом разбираться?**
начал изучать Google Cloud Messager, но есть сомнения, что это шаг в верном направлении. Рассмотрел возможность создания своего сервера под такие нужды, но понял, что пока не готов вкладывать время в его изучение.

Буду благодарен любым (особенно) русскоязычным ссылкам на то, что можно прочесть касательно программирования сетевого взаимодействия Андроид, и советам в каком месте интернета/девелопер гайда стоит покопаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без сервера никак не обойтись.
У вас должна быть информация и логика игры написана на сервере, с которого клиенты должны получать данные в свои телефоны.
Как это реализовать? Например, [своровать код из гугла](http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2014/08/implement-simple-android-chat.html) по созданию чата и переделать под свои нужды. Для сетевого взаимодействия здесь всё так же используется  класс `Socket`

Comment: м! поразбираюсь. Спасибо большое )